# How to use looping settimeout on sliding page to periodically load html template inside Framework 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 (framework7.io). The following code works fine on the main view page and uses a looping settimeout to reload signups.html every second:

```
<script type=“text/javascript” src=“code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js”></script>
<div id=“dnt” align=“center”></div>
<div id=“signups”></div>
<script language=“javascript”>
(function loop() {
document.getElementById(“dnt”).innerHTML = Date();
$(“#signups”).load(“signups.html”);
setTimeout(function () {
document.getElementById(“dnt”).innerHTML = Date();
$(“#signups”).load(“signups.html”);
loop()
}, 1000);
}());
</script>
```

However, if I place the code on a sliding page (signups.html) and click on it in main view (so that the signups.html slides in from right hand side of page), the settimeout does not work and the signups.html is not loaded. Here is the html of the sliding signups.html page:

```
<div class=“navbar”>
<div class=“navbar-inner”>
<div class=“left”><a href=“#” class=“back link”> <i class=“icon icon-back”></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
<div class=“center sliding”><font face=arial size=4 color=333333><B>Signups</b></font></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class=“pages”>
<div data-page=“signups” class=“page”>
<div class=“page-content”>
<div class=“content-block”>
<div class=“content-block-inner”>
<script type=“text/javascript” src=“code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js”></script>
<div id=“dnt” align=“center”></div>
<div id=“signups”></div>
<script language=“javascript”>
(function loop() {
document.getElementById(“dnt”).innerHTML = Date();
$(“#signups”).load(“signups.html”);
setTimeout(function () {
document.getElementById(“dnt”).innerHTML = Date();
$(“#signups”).load(“signups.html”);
loop()
}, 1000);
}());
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any tips would be appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval()` to call a function periodically which loads your data.

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```js
function loop() {
  //Uncomment below 2 lines in your code
  //document.getElementById(“dnt”).innerHTML = Date();
  //$(“#signups”).load(“signups.html”);
  console.log("In loop");
}

setInterval(function(){
  loop();
}, 1000); //keep your own time interval
```

Comment: The problem is not with settimeout itself but the fact that framework7 (with its own javascript structure) won't allow it to run on a sliding page - it works fine on the main view page. You need to test it inside framework7 to know what I mean. Also, I don't like setinterval as it can cause the browser to slow down and freeze up (from experience).